# Text processing in Nodejs and PHP

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I have two functions in php and javascript (nodejs) and both must give same result, but they didnt.

Why they give different result?

PHP:

```
base64_encode(sha1($string,1));
```

Javascript:

```
new Buffer(require("crypto").createHash("sha1").update(string,"utf8").digest("hex")).toString("base64");
```

Comment: I don't know the node.js functions, so I put this as a comment: your php code uses the raw binary output of sha1() as input for the base64_encode, while it seems to me that in the node.js code the sha1'ed string is converted to hex first. (see http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php for the use of the second parameter in sha1() )

Comment: thank you. really, this is problem.
Javascript version of function is wrong.
I used this:

    require("crypto").createHash("sha1").update(string,"utf8").digest("base64")

Comment: Hi uSide and welcome to Stackoverflow. You can accept your own answer (after a while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript version of function is wrong.
I used this:

```
require("crypto").createHash("sha1").update(string,"utf8").digest("base64")
```